# How to pass query parameter in form submit?

Tags: 8, forms

I have a form :

```
function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['edit'] = array(
          '#type' => 'textfield',
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => t('Go'),
          //'#markup' => "<div><a href='?word=1'>Go</a></div>",
        );
    return $form;
}
```

Now I want is; when I submit form,`$form_state->getValue('edit');` should get appended as a query parameter in form route.

Let's say my form route is:

```
mymodule.admin_page:
  path: '/mypage'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\myform'
```

And when I hit submit button of form, the route should get changed to `/mypage?word=$form_state->getValue('edit')`.

I tried below approach, but it is throwing error:

Created 1 more route with a parameter:

```
mymodule.word:
  path: '/mypage/{word}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\AdminController::myfunction'
```

And in my form submit function,

```
function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $data = $form_state->getValue('edit');
    $url = Url::fromRoute('mymodule.word',['word'=>$data]);
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
   }
```

But when I hit submit button, it is giving me error,

> Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException:
>   "Some mandatory parameters are missing"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stick with your original route definition:

```
mymodule.word:
  path: '/mypage'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\AdminController::myfunction'
```

Then set your submit handler to this:

```
function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $data = $form_state->getValue('edit');
  $url = Url::fromRoute('mymodule.word', [], ['query' => ['word' => $data]]);
  $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
}
```

Comment: tried, still giving same error, mandatory parameters are missing.

Comment: You either didn't put your route back to the original, or you didn't clear your cache. The path should be `'/mypage'`

Comment: Can you please share some other approach to achieve this? This is not working for me

Comment: There isn't another approach - how I told you to do it is how it's done!

Comment: I updated my code to show it all though.